# Get request failing to Google Cloud Storage Object from Google Compute Engine using Java API

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a servlet running under GCE which reads files from Google Cloud Storage. I am able to access the bucket and list the files and other metadata associated with the bucket. However when I try to execute a get request on a given object, I get a weird JSON parsing error shown below.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected numeric type but got class com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject
>     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:834)

My code is as follows

```
Storage.Objects.Get getObject = client.objects().get(BUCKET_NAME, "offers.txt");
StorageObject obj=getObject.execute();
```

As soon as the execute operation is called the exception is thrown. I doesnt seem to be access related below, I can list the files and insert files into bucket.

Any help is much appericiated

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
  <version>v1-rev7-1.19.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-api-client-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client-appengine</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client-gson</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you post the metadata of your object ? Also, what version of the library are you using ?

Comment: Added my POM to the question

Comment: Can you also add the metadata ? You can get it by running the same exact operation as you're trying in Java in the API Explorer. There's the link : https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get?hl=fr

Comment: Just a hunch. It looks like you're depending on version 1.18.0-rc of google-api-client, but google-api-services-storage depends on version 1.19.0 of google-api-client. Have you tried syncing to either 1.18 or 1.19?